# Adding custom CSS to the Wordpress Dashboard

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a `<li class="jobs-dashboard1">` I'd like to target with CSS. The problem is that it's not responding, so I wondered if it's possible to specify somehow with the id of the parent `<ul>` like so:

```css
#adminmenu.jobs-dashboard1 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="adminmenuback"></div>
<div id="adminmenuwrap">
    <ul id="adminmenu">
        <li class="wp-first-item wp-has-submenu wp-has-current-submenu wp- 
menu-open menu-top menu-top-first menu-icon-dashboard menu-top. 
first" id="menu-dashboard">
            <a href='index.php' class="wp-first-item 
wp-has-submenu wp-has-current-submenu wp-menu-open menu-top menu- 
top-first menu-icon-dashboard menu-top-first">
                <div class="wp-menu- 
arrow">
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                <div class='wp-menu-image dashicons-before 
dashicons-dashboard'><br /></div>
                <div class='wp-menu- 
name'>Dashboard</div>
            </a>
            <ul class='wp-submenu wp-submenu-wrap'>
                <li class='wp-submenu-head' aria-hidden='true'>Dashboard</li>
                <li class="wp-first-item current">.
                    <a href='index.php' class="wp-first-item current" aria- current="page">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href='update-core.php'>Updates 
<span class='update-plugins count-37'><span class='update. 
count'>37</span></span></a></li>
                <li class="jobs-dashboard1"><a href='https://adsler.co.uk/jobs-dashboard/' class="jobs. 
dashboard1">Jobs</a></li>
                <li class="post-job1"><a href='https://adsler.co.uk/post-a-job/' class="post-job1">Post A 
Job</a></li>
                <li class="events-dashboard1"><a href='https://adsler.co.uk/your-events-dashboard/' class="events. 
dashboard1">Events</a></li>
                <li class="post-event1"><a href='https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/' class="post-event1">Post 
An Event</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

This didn't work, and I don't know why.

[image]

If you see `Jobs` in the screenshot... that's one of them I'm trying to target.

The site is https://adsler.co.uk if that helps, but it's a backend modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you adding this CSS?  You cannot add it to typical CSS files that you use on your website, because those are all loaded on the Frontend, and not loaded in the Wordpress Dashboard.

You also shouldn't have to target your item with an ID before the class, if the item has its own class already, and is only used on that item.  If you use this class on more than one item then you can specify an ID or other selector.

**Add this to the end your functions.php or a custom plugin**

Here is the original posted solution:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_admin_css');

function custom_admin_css() {
  echo '<style>
    .jobs-dashboard1 {background: green;}
  </style>';
}
```

Here is another way that should also work.

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'custom_admin_css' );
function custom_admin_css() { ?>
<style>
    .jobs-dashboard1 {background-color: green; }
</style>
<?php }
```

Comment: I made an adjustment to the way the function is written that may work better, and not break anything.  Although both worked fine for me without breaking.  But when adding CSS to the backend, you can use this for inline, or add your styles to a CSS file that you then enqueue using the "admin_head" hook.  Much like you do for "wp_head" for frontend styles.

Comment: Ok, great.  Both the way I showed before, and this one should work.  Can keep this on in your back pocket for the future.  Glad it worked for you.

Comment: The first suggestion worked
`function custom_admin_css() {
  echo '
  <style>
    .jobs-dashboard1 {
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>';
}

add_action('admin_head', 'custom_admin_css');`

Comment: Can I use it with multiple classes too? Thanks

Comment: Like`. jobs-dashboard1.events-dashboard1`?

Comment: Yes, you can use it just like any other CSS you would add.  You just have to have it loaded on the backend, and as I said the "admin_head" hook is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have missed a space in your CSS declaration.

it should be,

```
#adminmenu .jobs-dashboard1 {background-color: green;}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but didn't work. Site is https://adsler.co.uk which probably doesn't help as it's a backend modification..

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have more layers of nodes over the ".jobs-dashboard1". So you could use this:

```
#adminmenu #menu-dashboard .wp-submenu .jobs-dashboard1{background-color: green;}
```

or if you want a cleaner way:

```
#adminmenu li ul .jobs-dashboard1{background-color: green;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works, Please check the below snippet. Also check [CSS Combinators](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)

```css
#adminmenu .jobs-dashboard1 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="adminmenuback"></div>
<div id="adminmenuwrap">
  <ul id="adminmenu">
    <li class="wp-first-item wp-has-submenu wp-has-current-submenu wp- 
menu-open menu-top menu-top-first menu-icon-dashboard menu-top. 
first" id="menu-dashboard">
      <a href='index.php' class="wp-first-item 
wp-has-submenu wp-has-current-submenu wp-menu-open menu-top menu- 
top-first menu-icon-dashboard menu-top-first">
        <div class="wp-menu- 
arrow">
          <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class='wp-menu-image dashicons-before 
dashicons-dashboard'><br /></div>
        <div class='wp-menu- 
name'>Dashboard</div>
      </a>
      <ul class='wp-submenu wp-submenu-wrap'>
        <li class='wp-submenu-head' aria-hidden='true'>Dashboard</li>
        <li class="wp-first-item current">.
          <a href='index.php' class="wp-first-item current" aria- current="page">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='update-core.php'>Updates 
<span class='update-plugins count-37'><span class='update. 
count'>37</span></span></a></li>
        <li class="jobs-dashboard1"><a href='https://adsler.co.uk/jobs-dashboard/' class="jobs. 
dashboard1">Jobs</a></li>
        <li class="post-job1"><a href='https://adsler.co.uk/post-a-job/' class="post-job1">Post A 
Job</a></li>
        <li class="events-dashboard1"><a href='https://adsler.co.uk/your-events-dashboard/' class="events. 
dashboard1">Events</a></li>
        <li class="post-event1"><a href='https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/' class="post-event1">Post 
An Event</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: nothing much. Your selection was wrong. `#adminmenu .jobs-dashboard1` this was the proper way to select

Comment: I have posted you the snippet and you can clearly see that works as per your posted code. Try `background-color: green!important;`

Comment: Then please update your code with the CSS and make it as working snippet, so we can go through that

Comment: How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: Check the code `</>` symbol in the answer box where you can insert HTML, JS and CSS in snippet